# Server not resolving remote names

Tags: windows-server-2008

I am running a Windows 2008 Server and after having Cablevision switch us over to a static IP my server cannot resolve certain names, namely mws.amazonservices.co.uk, mws.amazonservices.com, and smtp.gmail.com. The odd behavior here is on my machine I can resolve them fine. I have a ASP.NET application that when I run it on my machine as localhost it runs fine, once upload on the server I can't access those names. This is truly puzzling because I don't know how to even start troubleshooting this.

Comment: Try adding 8.8.8.8 as your secondary DNS on the server.

Comment: @George how do I do that?

Comment: What are your DNS settings on the server? Open up a CMD prompt and run, "ipconfig /all" to see them all.

Comment: When did you do the cutover to static?

Comment: @JoeTyman Go to control panel, under network and internet, select network sharing, click on change adapter settings, select the proper NIC, choose properties, IP4 and add to secondary DNS 8.8.8.8

Answer (score 0):

I changed my my DNS from 127.0.0.1 to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 per @George's suggestion. It works and everything runs much faster.

Comment: Good! Glad it worked!

Comment: Machines should always either point to themselves (if a DNS server) or a local DNS server (if a workstation), not public DNS. You should make the changes to the DNS section on the server, and add those DNS entries as forwarders. If this is an Active Directory network, expect issues with the config you just setup.

Comment: Totally agree with DanBig.  If nothing else, this is a massive security hole.  Just google "DNS command and control".